# Can't call View Controller method from app delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard

I'm trying to build the sample app from facebook iOS SDK but I'm using storyboards so it's a little different.

I'm doing this check in my AppDelegate.m application `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
 if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) {
    // To-do, show logged in view
} else {
    // No, display the login page.
    [self showLoginView];
}

return YES;
```

I've created a segue from my main `ViewController` to a navigation controller. The segue works fine if I trigger it using a button in my `ViewController` view, but I can't call that method from my `AppDelegate`.

The name of the method(that performs the segue) is `-displayLoginView` but I can´t find a way to point to the particular instance of my `ViewController`  that is active at launch.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your `UIApplicationDelegate` is not a view controller so it cannot initiate any segues.

You probably want to call `self.window.rootViewController` to get the `viewcontroller` in question but it might be easier to put that code in your `viewController`'s `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear` method instead of the app delegate.

Comment: If I use self.window.rootViewController nothing changes, other than the debugger telling me that I'm trying to present a viewcontroller that is not in the view hierarky.